# SQL get first and last transaction for each user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transaction table with 3 columns: transaction_id, user_id, time_created. I would like to output a table showing:

> `UserID    FirstTransactionTime    LastTransactionTime`

for each user. What is the best way to construct this query?

Comment: Does `FirstTransactionTime` and `LastTransactionTime` mean the earliest and latest transaction **start** time per user? I suggest you clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the earliest and latest transaction start time, per user:

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(time_created), MAX(time_created)
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY user_id
```